# Updating Form1's components from an external class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, class, real-time

My project's directory structure :

```
First_GUI
|_ First_GUI.sln
|_ First_GUI (Directory of same name)
  |_ Form1.cs
  |_ Insider (a directory inside First_GUI)
    |_ TestInnerClass.cs
```

I started C# last week and I'm trying to make a GUI application. `Form1` is the main form which has a `TextBox`, a `Button` and a `Label`.

User input a value in this textbox and when clicks on button, the value of that string is sent to a class residing in the `Insider` directory. The class which is receiving this value is named as `TestInnerClass`.

This `TestInnerClass` performs some action like adding some extra characters at the end of the received string. Now, I need it to update the `Label` we had in `Form1` and put the new string value in it.

The `TestInnerClass` has more instructions to do, so it should carry on and update the `Form1` in real time.

I have been trying for past 2 hours and I still haven't found a way to get this done.

I've tried to make the `Label` of `Form1` as `Public` to be accessed from anywhere and then did this in the `TestInnerClass` :

```
string newString = "Should update!";
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.Label.Text = newString;
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing another Threads properties (in your case the GUI Thread of the Form1) you need to Invoke the Thread like this:

```
frm1.Invoke( new Action(() => 
{ 
    frm1.label.Text = "Test"; 
} ));
```

The Invoke is required because the GUI of a Window in .net (doesn't matter if Forms or WPF) runs in it's own Thread. Threads execute code in parallel so the GUI is always responding to the user no matter what calculations happen in the background.

Long Story short:

```
 -> Entrypoint of your program
    |
    | -> Thread 1 (testInnerClass)
         |
         | -> Thread 2 (frm1.Show())
    |
    | -> Invoke Thread 2
    | -> set Property
         |
         | -> resume thread 2
```

When calling `Show()` your Form is in *another* Thread. Invoke pauses the Thread and you can change properties. When you're done it resumes.

This works, but after rereading your Question, it might not be the optimal solution, so here is another solution which may be better:

Edit the constructor of Form1 to:

```
public Form1 (string textForMyLabel) {
    Initialize();
    label1.Text = textForMyLabel;
}
```

and then creating the Form with `Form1 frm = new Form1(newString);`
then your label will be filled before you're calling the `Show()`-Method.
But this only works once for each instance of Form1.

Comment: tried it just after the `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();` line and it threw  `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.`

Comment: then do a `frm1.Show()` before. But there may be a better way to do this, like a configuration Context as Singelton or so.

Comment: Oh god, it worked! Thank you so much!. What's this "Invoke" though? Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: I'll add an explanation to my answer

Comment: I ran this again and now I see that it's opening another instance of the form. This will be a problem because if there are too many inputs or times I need to change, the app will make tons of instances. Isn't there anything that will edit the current running frame?

Comment: then keep track of your instances of your form with a variable, like `if(form1 == null) { }`